# Powershell script to start Chrome and more

Tags: google-chrome, powershell

I need a script that will start Google Chrome and then send a signal for it to go into full screen mode (usually done by hitting f11).

Chrome is installed to the default location.

An example of what I have tried is:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files(x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome"
```

This simple string is not even working for me.

Comment: so what have you tried, what doesn't work?

Comment: well im not by any means an actual powershell scriptor. ive tried looking up other scripts that should start the application but none seem to work for me.

Answer (score 11):

Sometimes a temporary folder is needed to get Chrome to start this way, so in those cases this might work.

```
$pathToChrome = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'
$tempFolder = '--user-data-dir=c:\temp' # pick a temp folder for user data
$startmode = '--start-fullscreen' # '--kiosk' is another option
$startPage = 'https://stackoverflow.com'

Start-Process -FilePath $pathToChrome -ArgumentList $tempFolder, $startmode, $startPage
```

Comment: This solution solved my problem with starting chrome as a different user (Parameter -Credential). The error message `Could not find file` was caused because of the missing temp folder argument. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

These types of questions are frowned upon due to you not stating what you have tried and you are just asking for a solution. 
However since this is simple I couldn't resist.
`Start-Process {Your full path to chrome.exe}\chrome.exe -ArgumentList '--start-maximized'`

Comment: Ok, im sorry, I just created my account to ask this question and did not know this. This is basically what I have already tried but I did not know I had to add the '-ArguementList' part Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're right that we like research and prior effort here, but we generally discourage meta-commentary from answers too. Keep answers focussed on answer material, and put advice in comments under the answer.