# Powershell chrome.exe force-device-scale-factor does not work

Tags: powershell, google-chrome, zooming

I am trying to open chrome with custom zoom size using powershell using following command

```
& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'  http://www.gnu.org/ /force-device-scale-factor=1.5  /incognito
```

Command opens the site in incognito mode. However, the zoom scale is still 100%. What could be going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was already half answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44335076/powershell-script-to-start-chrome-and-more)

I changed the code to be:

```
$pathToChrome = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'
$tempFolder = '--user-data-dir=c:\temp' 
$zoomScale = "--force-device-scale-factor=1.5"
$startPage = 'https://stackoverflow.com'

Start-Process -FilePath $pathToChrome -ArgumentList $tempFolder, $startPage, $zoomScale
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I am not getting a zoomed page. The page loaded is still 100% zoom and not 150%. Any Idea what could be wrong? Does it work fine for you?

Comment: @LogicIO Apologies, forgot to add the $tempFolder to the code. Try it now :)

Comment: Worked. Thanks :)