# Initialize google chrome by calling a variable

Tags: powershell, google-chrome

This is what I had in mind:

```
$chrome= (Start-Process "chrome.exe" "chrome:\\newtab")
$chrome
```

Pushing enter at the end of the first line loads chrome instantly.
But instead of typing in "Start-Process......." each time, there must be a way to get this simple code assigned to something that is faster to type.

When running the second line of the code it just does nothing.

Any ideas?

---

By the way, I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44335076/powershell-script-to-start-chrome-and-more) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19364189/instantiate-chrome-object-in-powershell/19368624#19368624) questions on this site but I still don't understand how to code this properly. I'm a total newcomer to this.

---

This is an edit in response to the answer given by @vonPryz

```
 PS C:\>function Launch-Chrome {Start-Process "chrome.exe" "chrome:\\newtab"}
Get-Process : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Launch-Chrome'.
At line:1 char:1
+ PS C:\>function Launch-Chrome {Start-Process "chrome.exe" "chrome:\\n ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Process], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetProcessCommand

PS C:\>Launch-Chrome
PS : Cannot find a process with the name "C:\>Launch-Chrome". Verify the process name and call the cmdlet again.
At line:1 char:1
+ PS C:\>Launch-Chrome
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\>Launch-Chrome:String) [Get-Process], ProcessCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoProcessFoundForGivenName,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetProcessCommand
```

Tried it in powershell 2 and 1 but still doesn't work sadly.

Comment: The function says `Start-Process`, but error says `Get-Process`. What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few ways to achieve this.

The first one is to create a function that launches Chrome. Like so,

```
PS C:\>function Launch-Chrome {Start-Process "chrome.exe" "chrome:\\newtab"}
PS C:\>Launch-Chrome 
# A new Chrome window appears!
```

Save the function in your [Powershell profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7) so that it'll be included on each new session. This might be the simplest solution, so try it first.

Another one is to create a script file that contains the function. Load the script either by dot-sourcing it on a session, or in your Powershell profile. If you need complex scripts, it might be worthwhile to maintain the scripts on separate path and just use profile to load those.

Third one is to create a [Powershell module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_modules?view=powershell-7) that contains the function. This is the most complex alternative out of the three solutions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, please see my edit. Which version of powershell are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your help, it won't let me create profile for some reason. But that is a question for another time....

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.

```
PS C:\function L-C {Start-Process "chrome.exe" "chrome:\\newtab"}
PS C:\ L-C
# Chrome window opens
```